# Python image scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

As part of my thesis I am trying to build a big training data corpus for [deep learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning).

My code runs on Conda 3.7 and works very well until I try to grab more than 80 images. In my case I would need a couple of hundred pictures.

#### Python code

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import io
import os
from PIL import Image
import hashlib

def fetch_image_urls(query:str, max_links_to_fetch:int, wd:webdriver, sleep_between_interactions:int=1):
    def scroll_to_end(wd):
        wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)

    # Build the Google query
    search_url = "https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&q={q}&oq={q}&gs_l=img"

    # Load the page
    wd.get(search_url.format(q=query))

    image_urls = set()
    image_count = 0
    results_start = 0
    while image_count < max_links_to_fetch:
        scroll_to_end(wd)

        # Get all image thumbnail results
        thumbnail_results = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("img.Q4LuWd")
        number_results = len(thumbnail_results)

        print(f"Found: {number_results} search results. Extracting links from {results_start}:{number_results}")

        for img in thumbnail_results[results_start:number_results]:
            # Try to click every thumbnail such that we can get the real image behind it
            try:
                img.click()
                time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)
            except Exception:
                continue

            # Extract image URLs
            actual_images = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('img.n3VNCb')
            for actual_image in actual_images:
                if actual_image.get_attribute('src') and 'http' in actual_image.get_attribute('src'):
                    image_urls.add(actual_image.get_attribute('src'))

            image_count = len(image_urls)

            if len(image_urls) >= max_links_to_fetch:
                print(f"Found: {len(image_urls)} image links, done!")
                break
        else:
            print("Found:", len(image_urls), "image links, looking for more...")
            time.sleep(1)
            return
            load_more_button = wd.find_element_by_css_selector(".mye4qd")
            if load_more_button:
                wd.execute_script("document.querySelector('.mye4qd').click();")

        # Move the result startpoint further down
        results_start = len(thumbnail_results)

    return image_urls

def persist_image(folder_path:str, url:str):
    try:
        image_content = requests.get(url).content

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"ERROR - Could not download {url} - {e}")

    try:
        image_file = io.BytesIO(image_content)
        image = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, hashlib.sha1(image_content).hexdigest()[:10] + '.jpg')
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            image.save(f, "JPEG", quality=85)
        print(f"SUCCESS - saved {url} - as {file_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"ERROR - Could not save {url} - {e}")

# As soon as the number of images is over 80, an error is shown
def search_and_download(search_term:str, target_path='./images', number_images=170):
    target_folder = os.path.join(target_path, '_'.join(search_term.lower().split(' ')))

    if not os.path.exists(target_folder):
        os.makedirs(target_folder)

    with webdriver.Chrome() as wd:
        res = fetch_image_urls(search_term, number_images, wd=wd, sleep_between_interactions=0.5)

    for elem in res:
        persist_image(target_folder, elem)

# Change here to modify the search query

search_term = 'Hecht'

search_and_download(
    search_term = search_term,
)
```

#### And the error in the log

> Found: 93 image links, looking for more ... 
> Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Scraping\image-gathering-selenium\scrapy2.py", line 103, in 
> search_term = search_term,
>
> File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Scraping\image-gathering-selenium\scrapy2.py", line 94, in search_and_download 
> for elem in res: 
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) is a package manager. Do you mean [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) (a Python distribution)? Please respond by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61406950/edit) (as appropriate), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to iterate over `res`, but it's `None`. That's why it throws an error.

Add an *if* condition:

```py
if res:
    for elem in res:
       persist_image(target_folder, elem)
```

Or add a blank list to this line:

```py
res = fetch_image_urls(search_term, number_images, wd=wd, sleep_between_interactions=0.5) or []
```

Comment: Thanks! The Error is gone, but somehow it still finds only up to 80 pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the return:

```
    else:
        print("Found:", len(image_urls), "image links, looking for more ...")
        time.sleep(1)
        # return
        load_more_button = wd.find_element_by_css_selector(".mye4qd")
        if load_more_button:
            wd.execute_script("document.querySelector('.mye4qd').click();")
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.